# Is there a Pythonic way of adding float values of one dictionary to a list of values in another dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, addition

Say that I have two Python dictionaries:

```
dictA = {20: [0.5, 1, 0.5], 25: [0.5, 1, 0.5]}
dictB = {20: 0.4, 25: 0.5}
```

The first dictionary contains keys with a list of floats as its value. The second one contains similar keys with a float value. I want the result to be the sum of the float value of dictB to each value in the list of dictA:

```
dictResult = {20: [0.9, 1.4, 0.9], 25: [1, 1.5, 1]}
```

I'm trying to do this one the simplest way possible without resorting to many lines of code; (wanted to make my code a bit more maintainable and readable in the future). Can this be accomplished using comprehensions?

Comment: Making your code maintainable generally doesn't mean "use less lines". Pythonic != using comprehensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension

```
{ k: [x + dictB.get(k,0) for x in l] for k, l in dictA.items() }
```

Output

```
{20: [0.9, 1.4, 0.9], 25: [1.0, 1.5, 1.0]}
```